# How can I change the write location in SheetJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, sheetjs

I'm using SheetJS to create excel workbooks in node.js, and I could not find anywhere in the documentation how to change the default location for saving the files. No problems with creating the excel file, successfully able to create the file in the root folder of my app.

What I tried:

```
excel.writeFile(workbook,"some/file/path"+SheetName)
```

The error message I get says the directory does not exist. This makes sense, as I intend to save the excel file in a newly created folder based on some variables. I cannot use predetermined folders.

Does anyone know how you can change the file path for the created workbook or programmatically create the folder(s) I need to make the above code work?

Thanks All,

Comment: Try the Tmp folder, there was a similar q&a the other day.

Comment: Do you have a link to the q&a your referring to? I can’t seem to find it. Also, wouldn’t the tmp folder contents disappear when the user closes the window?

Comment: No, I did not record or index that q&a, but it is on here. The Tmp folder gets emptied for sure on a reboot, whether the app will remove old Tmp files when it restarts is another possibility.